# Play Framework: access form when validation succeeds

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a form submission in Play 2.6 in which most validation can't be performed up front. The web application sends the submitted form data to a backend in another project, which will throw a GrammarException for most user errors. How can I propagate an error message and the original Form values back to the view

This is similar to [How to access my forms properties when validation fails in the fold call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221873/how-to-access-my-forms-properties-when-validation-fails-in-the-fold-call), but I need the form values on success.

```
form.bindFromRequest().fold(
  formWithErrors => {
    BadRequest(myView(newForm = formWithErrors)(request))
  },
  data => try {
    val results = MyBackend.build(data) // time-consuming
    Ok(views.html.myView(results)
  } catch { // catches most user errors
    case e: GrammarException =>
      val submittedForm = ....? //
      val formWithErrors = submittedForm.withGlobalError(e.getMessage)
      BadRequest(myView(newForm = formWithErrors)(request))
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already have the form with all the data from the request, so you can just use it.

```
val formWithBoundData = form.bindFromRequest()
formWithBoundData.fold(
  formWithErrors => {
    BadRequest(myView(newForm = formWithErrors)(request))
  },
  data => try {
    val results = MyBackend.build(data) // time-consuming
    Ok(views.html.myView(results)
  } catch { // catches most user errors
    case e: GrammarException =>
      val formWithErrors = formWithBoundData.withGlobalError(e.getMessage)
      BadRequest(myView(newForm = formWithErrors)(request))
  }
)
```

Comment: Perfect. I had misunderstood the bindFromRequest method. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to not use `try/catch` within your code while dealing with a call to another component (model, api, etc.), and here is why:

**Write concurrent code as much as possible**: In Scala/Play we have this wonderful world of `Future` that we can use to write concurrent code.  No need to "catch" anything, we rather use `recover`, when the method has the `Future` of something (e.g., `Future[Unit]`). So as much as possible write concurrent code. Try/catch is a Java like code, which could create misunderstanding on where the problem is; which brings me to the next point.

**What happens to the separation of concerns?**: If I try/catch in my controller, while I'm calling/using a method in my model for example, the fact is the `controller` is error handling the `model`'s errors? Why? If the model has an error, should the controller knows about its exact type? Or the controller should just know that there is an error (which type is not his/her business), and return an `InternalServerError` response to the views for example; or `BadRequesst`?.

The following code calls the model/back end, maps the return result, and in case of error its recovers the `Future` to a `BadRequest`:

```
form.bindFromRequest().fold(
  formWithErrors => {
    BadRequest(myView(formWithErrors)(request))
  },
  givenData =>  
    MyBackend.build(data).map{
      _ => Ok(views.html.myView(results) //When case is successful
    }.recover{ 
    //Any other exception that may occur while calling the other components other than the controller.
   case _       => {
      val formWithErrors = ??? 
      BadRequest(FormWithErrors)
   } 
   //Could build on that if you want to match an exact exception like GrammerException
  }
}
```

Benefits of the above approach:

**Concurrency and Separation of concerns**: already explained why.

**Scale to more than one calls**: Later if you have new constrains you can still use the above approach using `flatMap` for the outer call and `map` for inner calls and map to their successes and failures.

**More Exceptions**: You could expand within the `recover` block with more `exception` types, if you need to know the exact exception and provide the best error/warning message to the views.

Comment: Thanks—I upvoted for the great tips! However, it doesn't address the need for the controller to send the error back to the user with the accompanying form, which was the question. That need exists regardless of whether  `GrammarException` is referenced in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, the case class for Form has an error field: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L37

You can probably copy the received Form, add the errors, and return it, no?